# How to set cookie value in JavaScript and get it in Rails controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Using Ruby on Rails 5.0.3 .

I want to set some value in cookie using JavaScript (when button clicked), and get it in Rails.

I know how to access session in Rails, which is `session[:some_key]` or `cookies`.

But I don't know how to do in JavaScript. (it must be able to accessed from Rails `session` or `cookies`.)

How can I do it in JS?

Or any other ways to **save some value in JS, and get it later in Rails** ?

Comment: JS runs on the client and therefore is not able to directly affect the session, which is stored on the server. You could send an AJAX request from JS to the server which gets/sets the session values you require, though.

Comment: You'll need to make a server request from the client: take a look at [`XmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Okay, then I can use cookie? Anyway I want to save some value in JS, and get it later in Rails...

Comment: I want do it without sending request if I can.

Comment: why you don't you use browser cookies that you can access or set both from rails and from client side `cookies[:key]` in **Rails** and `document.cookie` to get the cookie list in **Client Side**.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't modify Rails session from the client side, even if it stored in cookies. Because the rails session is encrypted. As a solution, you can use regular cookies, not the Rails session.

Check http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
for more information.

Comment: Thanks! so Rails cookies does not get encrypted?

Comment: Yes, cookies are not encrypted and open for read and modification from the client side. The session is also cookies, in most cases, lets forget about the AR session storage, but all the data that are stored in Rails session are encrypted so without `secret_key_base` you can't modify or read this data from the client.

Comment: Can't you just set the cookie and send the value via ajax at the same time you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie for the rails app is just some hashed string to ID the server cookie, which has the data.

What they said, use Ajax to some controller method you write to update your necessary info into the rails cookie.