# How to get cookies in a different path in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

Using Ruby on Rails 5.0.3 .

Related to [How to set cookie value in JavaScript and get it in Rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410600/how-to-set-cookie-value-in-javascript-and-get-it-in-rails-controller?noredirect=1#comment85824713_49410600).

I'm using cookies to save some value like this.

```
var itemId = $(e.currentTarget).data('item-id');
document.cookie = 'clicked_item_id=' + itemId.toString();
```

The value is definitely saved in Cookies in `chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=localhost` .

[image: Chrome Cookies settings]
But I cannot access it in Rails like

```
cookies[:clicked_item_id]
```

or

```
cookies["clicked_item_id"]
```

This is because **where I save Cookies in JS and where I read Cookies in Rails are in different paths**. But I wanna share Cookies somehow.

How can I do this?

```
What I wanna do is this:
When users click an item, if he's not logged in,
pop up modal and let him go to login form(save item_id in JS).
After logged in(read item_id in Rails), redirect to the item detail page.
Because the pop up modal is implemented by JS, I must share values between JS and Rails.
```

Comment: This seems like it might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe you're trying to submit a form that includes your stored value? Or pass the value to the rails server when clicking a link?

Comment: What I wanna do is this: When users click an item, if he's not logged in, pop up modal and let him go to login form(save item_id in JS). After logged in(read item_id in Rails), redirect to the item detail page. Because the pop up modal is implemented by JS, I must share values between JS and Rails.